# Is there a pattern to create Akka-Actors if they're not present?

Tags: akka

I'm currently playing with Akka. My goal is to create a Telegram-Bot and handle the state of each chat with a separate Akka-Actor.

I have a component that receives messages from Telegram and that will forward the messages to the according actors. Therefore I have to create an actor for every new chat.
I don't want to do that in my Telegram-Query-Component since it shouldn't bother if an actor exists or not.
The path to the actors could be something like clients/*client-id*. If I send a message from the Telegram-Component to the path it ends up in the dead letter queue currently.

Is there a way that messages end up in the *clients*-parent-actor if the child actor is not present? Is there another way to automatically create actors if they are not present?
And: What's a common solution for my "problem" in the Akka-environment? Have something like a registry, or route every message via the *clients*-parent-actor per default?
Thanks for your help,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Akka clustering does this -- actors are created when a message is sent to them.

I've created actors to route messages, creating the recipient if needed. I don't think there's anything outside the clustering that does this automatically, but it's not difficult to implement.

Comment: And I can configure it so that it creates 1 actor per path, so I can have an actor for every chat / client-id that maintaines the state of the given workflow?

Comment: Specifically, it is cluster sharding which does this. If you use that, you will reference *entities* not actors as the entities might be migrated across nodes. Whenever you send a message to an entity, it will be automatically created. You should consult the docs on the details: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/cluster-sharding.html